# C++: How to output a string two letters at a time?

Tags: c++, string

I am trying to read from a file that contains sentences and output them two letters at a time.

```
 IE: 
    >hello world

 Output:
        he ll ow or ld
```

Here is what I have.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string input;

    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("wordpairs.txt");

    while(!infile.eof())
    {
        getline(infile, input);


        for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) //accidentally posted wrong code last time. My apologies.
        {
            cout << input[i] << input[i+1] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }



    infile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Edit & Run

and this is what it currently outputs for lets say for example, "hello world"

```
output:
       h he el ll lo ow eo or rl ld d
```

How do I fix it? I figure it has something to do with my for loop calling input[i + 1], but i dont know how to combine words other than doing that.

Comment: What you have cannot possibly compile, due to an obvious typo and will result in a compilation error. You cannot have possibly run the shown code, as you claim. Please show real code, instead of a fake code. The only thing you'll get in response to fake code, is fake answers. Although your pair of bugs appear to be quite obvious; since this is also obviously not the actual code that was compiled, discussing them will likely to be a waste of time.

Comment: You are incrementing `i` in your loop by `1`, should be `i += 2`. Then add a check inside the loop to make sure you are not accessing an element out of bounds.

Comment: Your desired output seems to ignore whitespace; seems like you'd need to do `infile >> c1 >> c2;` then `cout << c1 << c2;` over and over to mimic. (Modulo need to handle unevenly sized inputs)

Comment: Why have you edited your question with a possible solution that was posted bellow? This change your question completely

Comment: I meant to post my original code. I am working on two different things at a time, sorry about that. I am trynig to edit my code as suggested and trying to figure out how to impliment the check inside the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will print anything in pairs of 2 letters:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string input = "lo  zpxcpzx zxpc pzx cpxz c  lol";

    for (size_t i = 0, printed = 0; i < input.length(); ++i)
    {
        if (isspace(input[i]))
            continue;

        std::cout << input[i];
        printed++;

        if (printed % 2 == 0)
            std::cout << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Prints:

```
lo zp xc pz xz xp cp zx cp xz cl ol
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you so much. Just for my own sake, let me see if I understand the code correctly,

if(isspace(input[i]) is checking if there is a white space in the input (for the end of line)?

Then, if the printed / 2 has a remainder of 0, then print a space (for even? letters). and that prints out the input two letters at a time?

Comment: Yep. It skips all spaces and prints non space chars, after each 2 prints (n%2 == 0) it adds a space

Answer (score 2):

try to modify i++ to i+=2, because you need to skip the second as first

Comment: Yeah, but what happens when `i+1 == input.lenght()`?

Comment: Need to add condition as well

Answer (score 0):

The following takes two characters at a time and prints them. It uses the `for` syntax to initialize the chars and then to only proceed if reading two characters was successful.

```
for(char c1{}, c2{}; infile >> c1 >> c2;) {
    std::cout << c1 << c2 << ' ';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use this instead i+=2, in order to avoid repetition.
if it reaches length() , then try using i<s.length().
i have taken s as the string here

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).